# how to fetch data from two tables using sql

Tags: sql, oracle, db2

I need to get data from two tables, one with 10 columns and another with 8 columns.

Both have one common column with same data.

How can I write a query to get data from two tables like the below?

```
1 aa cc vv bb bb bb   ss   ff ff ff ff > from table 1

1 aa ss ff re df dfsd sfsd ss          > from table 2

2 aa cc vv bb bb bb   ss   ff ff ff ff > from table 1

2 aa ss ff re df dfsd sfsd ss          > from table 2
```

Like this one from table 1 and one from table 2 , in loop

Comment: You posted sample input (could have been simpler, though). What is desired output? Also, which database do you use? Is it Oracle or DB2?

Comment: Please post the structures of the two tables. This is highly pertinent for providing a workable solution.

Comment: Please, rewrite your question with `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT INTO` (with some sample data) statements for both tables and the result desired on this sample data.

Answer (score 0):

You can try "natural joining" the two tables like:

SELECT *
FROM table_1 natural join table_2
WHERE *any condition if necessary*;

This will give you all the data from both the tables.

Comment: i need to get data one after the other .. line by line

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNION ALL like the below and for not common columns you can use null.

```
       WITH sub1
     AS (SELECT ROWNUM rw,
                d.*
         FROM   table1 d),
     sub2
     AS (SELECT ROWNUM rw,
                b.*
         FROM   table2 b),
sub3 as(SELECT common_col1,null not_common,rw from sub2
union all
select common_col1,not_common,rw from sub1)
select common_col1,not_common from sub3 order by rw
```